# WSO2 governance registry - Asset permissions

Tags: wso2

I'm using WSO2 governance registry and i wish to enable public visibility for all assets already loaded.I can do this via the GUI using the admin user but is there any way to do this for all assets in bulk or via the API ? 
Also , can i enable by default for an asset to be public ?

Comment: Show us what you have so far

Answer (score 0):

Using the admin user, you will be able to do this very easily. First, you have to login to the admin console. Then using the Registry browse option, navigate to asset stored registry path. Ex: SOAP Services are stored in `/_system/governance/trunk/soapservices/` collection.

There you can see `Permissions` panel and using it, you will be able to set the visibility of the assets to the public user.

[image]

Comment: I know this asked in the original question but is there a way to make the asset publically viewable just using the Governance Rest API?